# How can I get a real average from many measurements?

Tags: measure-theory, average

I am measuring fuel level from a car. I am getting too many different values.

for example:

the real value on the car's board is 50%.

when I measure 10 successive values: 51% | 50% | 49% | **56%** | 51% | 49% | **48%** | 50% | **53%** | **54%**

So I calculated the average and I get 51%!  (sometimes I get a difference of 5% and 6%)

two values are different (50% and 51%) because of perturbations values like 56%. so how can we use a simple equation to eliminate the perturbation and get a real measure?

thank you

Comment: I guess what you're looking for is : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval

Comment: One idea could be to take the median instead of the mean.